# Complex number, absolute value and triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Hi I was wondering if the following statement can be true 
$|1+a|= 1+|a|$ where $a$ is a complex number i.e $x+iy$ ?

I understand there is the triangular inequality but I was wondering if the $1$ in the absolute would simplify it ?

Comment: It is not a formal explanation but it clearly is not. Since it doesn't work for real numbers. Take a=-3 it does not work for this (2 is not equal to 4)

Comment: It is true if $a$ is a non-negative real, and every real number is a complex number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true if and only if the imaginery part is zero and the real part is non negative.

Only if part: Let $a=x+yi$.

$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}=1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$\implies (x+1)^2+y^2=x^2+y^2+1+2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$\implies 2x=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$\implies x^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$\implies y=0$$

And for $x$ being real,

$$|x+1|=1+|x|$$

$$\implies x^2+2x+1=x^2+2|x|+1$$

$$\implies x=|x|$$

$$\implies x\geq 0$$

Comment: Are you saying it's true for $a=-1$?

Comment: Oh right, I did not read the comments carefully, I will add proof for the non-negative part.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation @cr001:)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a=x+yi$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$|1+x+yi|=\sqrt{\Re(1+x+yi)^2+\Im(1+x+yi)^2}=\sqrt{(1+x)^2+(y)^2}=\sqrt{y^2+(1+x)^2}$$